# How to get coordinates of a polygon from an embedded esri map using JavaScript and REST API?

Tags: javascript, html, rest, api, esri

I have an HTML file and I have embedded a map service or an esri map to it. When I run this html file, I can see the embedded map and I can draw polygons on that map. I also need to get the coordinates of the vertices of the polygon. How can I do that using JavaScript an REST API or any API? Please help. One the code I have removed the link to the service as it is private. Please see code below.

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
 <center> 
        <h1 style="color:green"> 
          Test 
      </h1> 
  <p>Test</p>
   <embed src="" 
               width="1000" 
               height="1000"
               style="border:none;" /> 
 </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i think you actually must use `esri javascript api` .

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this by using an embed. You need to use the [Esri JavaScript API](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/)  to place a `Map` object into a div and perform any interactions through the JavaScript API directly.

Here is a [tutorial from Esri about placing a feature layer on a map](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/add-layers-to-a-map/).

This tutorial shows [how to put custom graphics and draw points, lines, and ploygons on a map](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/draw-graphics/).

Following the second tutorial you should get something like this:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>ArcGIS JavaScript Tutorials: Create a Starter App</title>
  <style>
    html, body, #viewDiv {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.13/esri/css/main.css">
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.13/"></script>

  <script>  
    require([
      "esri/Map",
      "esri/views/MapView",
      "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
      "esri/widgets/Sketch",
    ], function(Map, MapView, GraphicsLayer, Sketch) {

      var graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();

      var map = new Map({
        basemap: "topo-vector",
        layers: [graphicsLayer]
      });

      var view = new MapView({
        container: "viewDiv",
        map: map,
        center: [-118.80500,34.02700],
        zoom: 13
      });

      var sketch = new Sketch({
        view: view,
        layer: graphicsLayer
      });

      view.ui.add(sketch, "top-right");

    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="viewDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, this only uses esri's built in "Sketch" widget. If you don't want to allow points and lines to be drawn you will need to look into the [Sketch widget docs](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Sketch.html) to see if you can limit the functionality. I researched for you and looks like you can with the `availableCreateTools` property. The default is `["point", "polyline", "polygon", "rectangle", "circle"]` so this code should allow only polygons:

```
      var sketch = new Sketch({
        view: view,
        layer: graphicsLayer,
        avaliableCreateTools: ["polygon"]
      });
```

The Esri example also doesn't show how you can perform any actions once the user is done creating something. After the user is done, you can listen to the `create` event with:

```
sketch.on('create', function(event) {
   // Check if the sketch is completed:
   if (event.state === "complete") {
       // Polygon has been created
   }
});
```

This event can be found on the "events" section in [Esri's Sketch Widget documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Sketch.html#events-summary)

Comment: Hi R10t, thank you very much for the response. I am a bit lost, I am also new to APIs and Esri Maps, can you please give me an example?

Comment: Hello @SiyabongaKubeka, I updated my answer. Hopefully this helps.